# xpages hiding/showing fields based on a combobox value

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm using a `<xe:djTabContainer>` with 10 `<xe:djTabPane>` containing numerous fields components.

There is a principal combobox whose value will determine which fields to be showed or not and in this way the document structure will be achieved.

If I will use this approach, then for all my >50 fields which I want to show/hide, I will use only the `onChange` event of the combobox?

Considering the fact that there are >50 fields which enter in this category < showing&hiding them >, should I use another approach / method? Thanks for your time.

```
<xp:comboBox value="#{Contr.txt_tipcontractcv}" id="comboBox4">                                 <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">                                      
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ""}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(),"SetupvwTipuriContracteC",1);}]]>           </xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>                   
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="false">                                       <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:FisaP}", {
});
]]></xp:this.script>                                    </xp:eventHandler>                          </xp:comboBox>
```

and the panel:

```
<xp:panel id="FisaP">
        <xp:label id="label4"
            style="color:rgb(128,0,0);font-family:verdana;font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Fisa contract "+ Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv")}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv") != ""
         }]]></xp:this.rendered>

        </xp:label>

    </xp:panel>
```

Comment: may be you can check if combo.getSubmittedValue() will return a value.

Comment: @FrankvanderLinden I tried modify with: var comboVal = combo.getSubmittedValue(); , but still no work for me.

Comment: and if you print(comboVal) maybe will give it a clue of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would turn it around. Let the labels and fields ask the combobox if they should be rendered or not. Let the combobox's onchange event initiate a partial refresh of a panel which includes all fields you want to show/hide.

If your >50 fields are all on one place you can frame them with a panel and set the rendered property there.

If your combobox is bound to a viewScope variable the rendered property of fields/labels would be

```js
rendered="#{javascript:viewScope.tipcontractcv1 == 'Vanzare-Cumparare'}"
```

or if it is bound to a document field then

```js
rendered="#{javascript:document1.getItemValueString('txt_tipcontractcv1') === 'Vanzare-Cumparare'}"
```

**Update:**

Based on your code in your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636661/2065611 take the following steps so get it to work with the Dojo Tab Container:

1.

Put the labels and fields in panels which do have an id but **don't** have a rendered attribute

```js
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:label value="Persoane spre informare" ... id="label2">   
         <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv1") == "Vanzare-Cumparare"
         }]]></xp:this.rendered>
    </xp:label>
    ... other label and fields ...
</xp:panel>
```

You can create other panels "panel2", "panel3", ... too. They can be placed in different djTabPanes.

2.

Change the `onchange` event of your combobox and execute client side code to refresh the panels

```js
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onchange"
                submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                    XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panel1}", {
                        onComplete: function() {
                            XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:panel2}");
                        }
                    });
                ]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
```

3.

You can optimize your code if you put labels and fields with the same rendered attribute together into an additional panel

```js
<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:panel id="panelRendered1"
         <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv1") == "Vanzare-Cumparare"
         }]]></xp:this.rendered>
        <xp:label value="Persoane spre informare" ... id="label2" />   
        ... other label and fields ...
    </xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: I added: <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:Contr.getItemValueString("txt_tipcontractcv1") == "Vanzare-Cumparare"}]]></xp:this.rendered> . but I guess I need to do the partial refresh to the respective fields. Could you give me an example of how to partial refresh, let say, 4 fields? Considering the fact that my fields are not on the same panel, unfortunately, but on different djTabPanes.

Comment: Here is a good description how to partially refresh more than one id: http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP

Comment: In the .getItemValueString ( " // here is the id of the field " ? )

Comment: I;m getting an error: no element to submit with id view:_id1:_id2:_id50:djContentPane1:djTabPane1:label2 ( the id is label2 )

Comment: You can only partially refresh elements which are rendered. So put fields in panels which have an id and always get rendered OR partially refresh your whole djTabContainer.

Comment: The code for partial refresh: xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:djTabPane1}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:djTabPane1}", {
            onComplete: function(){ } 
        });
    }
});]]> , and also i compute the rendered property for the field but now I get the error: Cannot read property ''replaceChild'' as null

Comment: It isn't working, the target label isn't show or hide. I will post my code in an answer, to see my attempts.

Comment: I updated my answer. It works perfect for Dojo Tab Container this way, at least in my sample.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The main idea, from what I understood, is to try to group the fields in panels, so that you call a small number of partialgetrefreshes. Unfortunately, I have multiple fields on different tabs, but I can Call multiple partialrefreshes from client side for the respective ids.

Comment: The panels you refresh (without the rendered attribute) can contain also the parts which not depend on your combobox. So, you need to define max one panel per djTabPane. The panels from point 3 are for optimization only where you need to write just one rendered attribute for several fields and labels in such an additional panel.

Comment: I see now. So, let say I have 4 tabs in my Container. I can define in each tab only 1 panel, having on this panel both type of fields: which will be hided or not ( for those which I want to hide, I just add the <rendered> attribute ). In this way, I only refresh 4 ids:panel[i], i=1..4. So, the panel(s) will refresh, and from this the fields which have the rendered attribute will hide, others wont, right?

Comment: Does xe:djTabPane have `partialRefresh="false"`? That is important.

Comment: No. the panel which I want to refresh is outside the djContainer.

Comment: The partialRefreshPost does work for me for your changed code in question. How does your combobox code look like which has the onchange event?

Comment: Your code does work perfect for me. There must to be something else causing the issue. Please, try it in a simple new XPages: just your code above and the data source definition. Does that work?

Comment: I did now, but without placing the combobox in a djContainer, with some djTabs .. It works... but what is causing the issue in my application? It gives me headache for some time.

Comment: Also, I try the code for refreshing a panel INSIDE the djTab and it works. Shouldn't it work also for a panel which is outside the djContainer?

Comment: Ok, you have a simple working example now. Try to add piece by piece from your original full XPage and look when it breaks. Or, delete piece by piece from your full XPage and look when it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60803/discussion-between-knut-herrmann-and-mfg-flay).

Answer (score 2):

First...  never do this:

```
if (comboVal == "Vanzare-Cumparare")
```

Even though it's called "SSJS"..  it's really not "JavaScript"... you're pretty much working with Java.  In Java everything is an object.  Even a literal string.  So by entering "Vanzare-Cumparare" you're pretty much creating a new Object.  You can see this in the typeahead of the SSJS editor.  Try typing "anything".   <-- Note you NEED to type in that period.

The way to do that if statement is:

```
if ("Vanzare-Cumparare".equalsIgnoreCase(comboVal)
```

you could reverse it I think:

```
if (comboVal.equalsIgnoreCase("Vanzare-Cumparare")
```

Should give you the same result.  I think sometimes you can get away with using the == but mostly likely it's going to bite you at some point no matter what.  So I recommend never doing that.

I'm not sure I'm following your approach here.  I guess it makes some sense but if it were me I'd do it differently.  I know that personally I've NEVER tried to grab the component in SSJS like this:  var combo:javax.faces.component.UIComponent  - I've never seen the need.
I'd prefer to use a scoped variable and then in the label's rendering property grab that scoped variable and use that to determine your rendering value - true or false.

Comment: I would combine the answers: a) use a binding and not a UI element to decide the rendering (after all the rendering is not based on a UI decision, but a business decision, so the model should drive it) b) use the .equalIgnoreCase c) the partial refresh d) group fields in xp:panels or xp:div to minimize the number of rendered evaluations you need to do

Answer (score 0):

I see a real problem. If the component is not currently rendered, you cannot get a handle to it with getComponent. If you simply change the display value, then the component is always there, even if it's not displayed.

Something like this:

```
var combo:javax.faces.component.UIComponent = getComponent("txt_tipcontractcv1");
var comboVal = combo.getValue(); 
if (comboVal.equalsIgnoreCase("Vanzare-Cumparare")) {
    document.getElementById("#{id:label2}").style.display = "block"; // or "inline"
} else {
    document.getElementById("#{id:label2}").style.display = "none";
}
```

You need to ensure that the label2 element is always rendered, so that the style indicates whether it is visible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Running on the Client side, "document" would rerpesent the datasource of the xpage?

Comment: No, document is actually window.document in simple javascript. No reference to the datasource at all.