# xpages tab container partial refresh

Tags: dojo, xpages

I make a partialRefresh on a tab container with  4 tabs:

```
 <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="djContentPane1">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("hideRelatedDocuments", true);}]]></xp:this.action>
   </xp:eventHandler>
```

The viewScope is then used to some fields which I want to hide/show. Those fields lay on the tab container.

And after this, the tab container looks strange:

[image]

What might be the problem? Thanks for your time.

I tried adding a mainPanel, and on this panel I added the TabContainer. Then, I updated the panel but sttill, no work. The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh the fields to show/hide them depending on current value in combobox field if you

- put the fields into panels which have an id and always gets rendered
- place the panels into the Tab Panels
- refresh all panels on onchange event of your combobox with `XSP.partialRefreshPost`s

Look for the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623177/2065611).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're refreshing the content pane. I've not pinned down the cause, but refresh either an area outside the Dojo Tab Container or a panel/div that's inside the Tab Container Pane you want to refresh.

I suspect it's something to do with Dojo then processing the response HTML. As a client-side framework, I don't think Dojo is really designed to handle replacing HTML by injection into an existing page.

Tommy Valand added a snippet to handle this problem: http://dontpanic82.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/fix-for-partial-refresh-on-dojo-tab.html

Comment: I see. The problem is the fields I want to show/hide are all in this one djContentPane but on different tabs. I thought if I'll refresh the contentPane, it will work.

Comment: Refreshing a panel outside the Tab container may work. Otherwise you may need to chain refreshes using onComplete event of the eventHandler

Comment: I tried refresh a panel. I've updated the question with a picture, still no work for me.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the link previously. I've never worked with Dojo events, and I don't know how to use the snippet. Seems like I have to spend more time to understanding it.

Comment: I've added the function from http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/01/xpages-hijackingpublishing-partial.html , and then in the addOnLoad property the code from the link, but I'm getting: dojo not found. Seems that to refresh a contentPane is too difficult to achieve with simple code.